# Electron MacOS app 'Not Available for Testing' in Testflight

Tags: node.js, macos, electron, electron-builder

I'm working on a universal MacOS app in Electron, and while I've gotten pretty far, I can't seem to figure out how to enable it for testing in Testflight.

I keep running into the following error in App Store Connect no matter what I do:

[image: Not Available for Testing in Testflight]

I'm using:

- electron-builder: 23.0.8
- electron: 17.4.3
- electron-builder-notarize: 1.4.0

I'm building on an M1 Macbook Air, Monterey 12.3.1.

Varying useful stuff I've found:

- https://github.com/electron/osx-sign/issues/251
- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/689377
- https://jondot.medium.com/shipping-electron-apps-to-mac-app-store-with-electron-builder-e960d46148ec
- https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/mac-app-store-submission-guide
- https://til.simonwillison.net/electron/sign-notarize-electron-macos

### My setup

#### package.json

```
    "build": {
        "appId": "com.xxxxx.xxxxxx",
        "afterSign": "electron-builder-notarize",
        "mac": {
            "category": "public.app-category.entertainment",
            "darkModeSupport": true,
            "hardenedRuntime": true,
            "gatekeeperAssess": false,
            "entitlements": "build/entitlements.mac.plist",
            "entitlementsInherit": "build/entitlements.mac.plist",
            "icon": "build/icon.icns",
            "target": [
                {
                    "target": "mas",
                    "arch": "universal"
                },
                "dmg"
            ]
        },
        "mas": {
            "type": "distribution",
            "hardenedRuntime": false,
            "provisioningProfile": "embedded.provisionprofile",
            "entitlements": "build/entitlements.mas.plist",
            "entitlementsInherit": "build/entitlements.mas.inherit.plist"
        }
    }
```

#### entitlements.mas.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
        <string>TEAMID.com.app.appname</string>
        <key>com.apple.application-identifier</key>
        <string>TEAMID.com.app.appname</string>
        <key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
        <string>TEAMID</string>
        <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-dyld-environment-variables</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

#### entitlements.mas.inherit.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.inherit</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 3):

After looking through all these, and just playing around with adding different entitlements, it was resolved with the following settings. I honestly have no idea which of these is relevant at this point, and after days of debugging I am beyond the point of caring haha. But for future internet travelers who find themselves stuck, here is what I have that got me through:

[image: Successful electron macos appstore submission]

### package.json relevant section (added loginhelper!)

```
"build": {
    "appId": "com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx",
    "afterSign": "electron-builder-notarize",
    "mac": {
        "category": "public.app-category.entertainment",
        "darkModeSupport": true,
        "hardenedRuntime": true,
        "gatekeeperAssess": false,
        "entitlements": "build/entitlements.mac.plist",
        "entitlementsInherit": "build/entitlements.mac.plist",
        "icon": "build/icon.icns",
        "target": [
            {
                "target": "mas",
                "arch": "universal"
            },
            "dmg"
        ]
    },
    "mas": {
        "type": "distribution",
        "hardenedRuntime": false,
        "provisioningProfile": "embedded.provisionprofile",
        "entitlements": "build/entitlements.mas.plist",
        "entitlementsInherit": "build/entitlements.mas.inherit.plist",
        "entitlementsLoginHelper": "build/entitlements.mas.loginhelper.plist"
    }
}
```

### entitlements.mas.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
        <string>TEAMID.com.app.appname</string>
        <key>com.apple.application-identifier</key>
        <string>TEAMID.com.app.appname</string>
        <key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
        <string>TEAMID</string>
        <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-dyld-environment-variables</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-only</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

### entitlements.mas.inherit.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.inherit</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

### entitlements.mas.loginhelper.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: did u ever published electron app in app store ? my app is visible at test flight but crashes everytime i try to open it  any clues ?

Comment: @binar I ran into the same issue. No idea what the problem is, I had to take a mental break: https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/4553#issuecomment-1125355710

Comment: ok so my problem was setting sandbox true in webPreferences 
also adding additional config for webpack in craco (spent only 2 weeks on that)
in addition some of entitlements were wrong

Comment: Are you building with `electron-osx-sign` and then `productbuild` to generate a PKG to upload with Transporter? I'm battling the same issue as your original question and I feel like my entitlements are correct.

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't resolved things for me. The barrier to getting electron built, signed and through the app store is so high it is killing any motivation to develop in the electron sphere

Comment: @spartygw Did you find the resolutions? My app still crashes all time when opening it.

Comment: @HardikKothari sorry, no.